# Conditional Query in T-SQL for getting records from multiple databases and tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have a clause like this:

*Give me all contracts where `IsDeleted` is 0 **AND** 
where `UstrojstvenaJedinicaId` is equal to procedure parameter (`@zavodId`)

**OR**

there is only one `UstrojstvenaJedinicaId` and that `UstrojstvenaJedinicaId` is = 'HCPHS'*

Example:

Procedure parameter `zavodId = 5;`

So in this example, I want to get all contracts `where UstrojstvenaJedinicaId = 5` and only those contracts because we met the requests in first part of where clause.

If it helps, this is my C# code which is good and works and SQL query should be like this:

```
.Where(x => x.UstrojstveneJedinice.Any

(y => y.UstrojstvenaJedinicaId == zavodId) ||

x.UstrojstveneJedinice.All(y => y.UstrojstvenaJedinicaId == 10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking for:

```
IF ( (SELECT COUNT(table.id)  FROM *Tablename* WHERE UstrojstvenaJedinicaId =  'HCPHS') = 1)  

BEGIN 

(SELECT *  FROM  *Tablename* WHERE UstrojstvenaJedinicaId =  'HCPHS')
END
ELSE

(SELECT * FROM  *Tablename* WHERE  isdeleted = 0  and UstrojstvenaJedinicaId = @zavodId)
```

Comment: Sorry for all the edits. I think this final one meets your intended logic